# Why does Windows 11 window turn into Windows 95 window for a few seconds after the close command?

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-95

## Problem

I have a window that when I send the close command, for a few seconds it turns into a Windows 95 window before the window closes.

| Before close | Few seconds after close command |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

---

My computer is on windows 11, and I'm using python tkinter.

## Question

May I know if this is a windows behaviour, or if not, this is just a tkinter behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May I know if this is a windows behaviour, or if not, this is just a
> tkinter behaviour?

I looked at this article and read through the things it can do.

[tkinter behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html)

I have two Windows 11 machines here:  1 Production and 1 Insider and have been running Windows 11 for near 6 months.

The behavior you show (seconds after close) is completely non-standard on either of my machines at any point in time.

So I suggest you look at tkinter and how you are using it.